# Can't compile and run latest examples in ns3 tutorial

Tags: ns-3

I'm not a communications engineer and I am basically trying to learn ns3 by my own for some project. I'm reading the [ns3 manual](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/tutorial/html/tracing.html), specifically the "Tracing" section. For some reason,in trying to run `fifth.cc` and `sixth.cc` I get the error message

```
 (...)
 fatal error: tutorial-app.h: No such file or directory
   16 | #include "tutorial-app.h"
 (...)
```

I don't think I am using an old tutorial and/or newer ns3 version. I installed ns3 from github, though. Any ideas?

Comment: how are you running it? For instance, copying to scratch folder and useing ns3 bin (cmake wrapper).

Comment: Yes, I copied the files to the scratch folder. Actually I notice that for some reason the last examples won't compile in scratch, but in the /examples/tutorials folder. Probably I will raise an issue about this.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when the "tutorial-app.h" file is out of sync with NS3's Github repository!!

In order to solve this issue, copy paste following files [from github](https://github.com/nsnam/ns-3-dev-git/blob/master/examples/tutorial/) to your local NS3 install.

- [tutorial-app.cc](https://github.com/nsnam/ns-3-dev-git/blob/master/examples/tutorial/tutorial-app.cc)
- [tutorial-app.h](https://github.com/nsnam/ns-3-dev-git/blob/master/examples/tutorial/tutorial-app.h)
- [sixth.cc](https://github.com/nsnam/ns-3-dev-git/blob/master/examples/tutorial/sixth.cc)